# Tracing a deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am receiving this warning in my program, I have recently updated to Node 10 and I'm trying to figure out the source of the deprecation warning:

`[DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated`

How can I trace where this error originates?

PS. I've tried `--trace-warnings` and `--trace-deprecation` on the CLI, getting no luck

Comment: Node v10. It happens.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_deprecation

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, It's my code and I'm trying to fix it, I've got no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Explain downvote??

Comment: So you are asking how to find `.inspect` calls in your code?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, it's in one of my dependencies, and it could be in any of the tens of deep-dependencies. It's not in my code

Comment: Ok... and? Clarify you question. What exactly do you want to do? I'm quite sure stacktrace gives you which module uses deprecated way to define custom inspect method.

Comment: There is no stack trace, that's the problem

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**OP Here**

Since `--trace-warnings` and `--trace-deprecation` didn't show a stacktrace, I found another way that did:

```
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
    console.log(warning.stack);
});
```

Comment: Where should I start that?

Comment: worked for me too

Comment: Add that to the top level file that your node script runs.

Answer (score 8):

Use `NODE_OPTIONS`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--trace-deprecation react-scripts start",
},
```

Answer (score 4):

This one did the job:

```
npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--trace-deprecation [original_command]
```

Example:

```
npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--trace-deprecation npx webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem before, And my problem has been solved ,The reason for my problem was the extension (color highlights), Since it was downloaded, the server has stopped working After deleting this damn addition, the problem was solved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1CdG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for reviewing the answer

Answer (score -1):

I did the following setting to remove the message ((node: 11172) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.).

Append to my database connector useCreateIndex: true

try {
await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_MONGO, {
useNewUrlParser:true,
useUnifiedTopology:true,
useFindAndModify:false,
useCreateIndex : true , //  DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureInd
} );

Comment: This does not relate to the question. Yes the error message is similar, a deprecation warning - this only means that the method you use is going to be removed in the future and is not advised to use. It can happen in any javascript code. You posted mongoose specific code.